# Finding furthest node from given node in general tree

Tags: algorithm

Example tree:

```
                1
              /    \
             2      3
            / \    / \
           4   5  6   7
          /        \
         8          9
        / \
       10  11
```

Given a random node. Say 6. How would I find the furthest node from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only given the tree there is no way around exploring the whole tree O(n). Here is a simple algorithm, traversing the tree and visiting each node once:

```
int maxD;
Node furthest;
Node findFurthest(Node node) {
    maxD = 0;
    furthest = node;
    Node prev = null;
    for (int d = 0; node != null; d++) {
        explore(node, d, prev);
        prev = node;
        node = node.parent;
    }
    return furthest;
}
void explore(Node node, int d, Node prev) {
    if (node == null)
        return;
    if (d > maxD) {
        maxD = d;
        furthest = node;
    }
    if (node.left != prev)
        explore(node.left, d + 1, null);
    if (node.right != prev)
        explore(node.right, d + 1, null);
}
```

If you would save the max depth on each edge or on the nodes then you could answer the query in O(logn) by going up to the root checking and comparing depths and then go down to the leaf with the furthest distance. Although this is only true if you just have to return one of the furthest nodes and not all of them if they have the same distance.